# JAX-RS Frameworks with Client Caching

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, restlet, resteasy

Do RESTEasy, Jersey or Restlet integrate client sided caching?

I read something about a CacheClient for [Jersey](http://code.google.com/p/smart-util/wiki/JerseyCacheClient)

Is that an official implementation? If not, are they working on Client Caching for Jersey 2.0? Can someone confirm this?

For Resteasy I read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/Cache_NoCache_CacheControl.html) something about official client sided cache control.

Im not sure about Restlet. Are there some official good solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Restlet, we are planning to add a caching service in version 2.2. That will benefit the JAX-RS extension as well.

See our [detailled roadmap](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/175-restlet.html) here.

Comment: If there is no one else posting details to jersey and resteasy, I will accept this answer in one day. Thanks.